# useDebounce Hook doesn't allow me to type

Tags: reactjs, debouncing

I am trying to make a simple debouncing hook (implementation from a video) and use it in the Context but it doesn't work. More interestingly, it does not allow me to type anything in the input. I store handler functions and state in the Context and passing necessary things to child components.

useDebounce.js

```
import { useState } from 'react';

export default function useDebounce() {
  const [typingTimeout, setTypingTimeout] = useState('');

  function debounce(func, wait) {
    clearTimeout(typingTimeout);
    const timeout = setTimeout(() => {
      func();
    }, wait);

    setTypingTimeout(timeout);
  }

  return debounce;
}
```

Context API

```
 const [text, setText] = useState('');
 const debounce = useDebounce();

 const handleSearch = e => {
    if (e.target.value === '' || e.target.value.match(/^[0-9]+$/)) {
       debounce(() => setText(e.target.value), 1000);
    }
  };
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is in this line. When the timeout is executed the `e.target.value` is null/undefined. The state updates is async process and the event parameter here is a `Synthetic Event` and is [pooled](https://reactjs.org/docs/events.html#event-pooling) (**Only relevant forReact <=16**). This means that the SyntheticEvent object will be reused and all properties will be nullified after the event handler has been called.

```
debounce(() => setText(e.target.value), 1000);
```

This part `setText(e.target.value)` inside timeout won't work:

Change it to:

```
const value = e.target.value; //--> store the value
debounce(() => setText(value), 1000);
```

Comment: Events are no longer pooled [as of v17](https://reactjs.org/docs/legacy-event-pooling.html).

Comment: @lawrence-witt the link is the same I posted..Yes, I asume that he is using a minor version, and that is why the input value is not updated because e.target.value is null. What do you think? thanks I will add it as a note

Comment: That's a perfectly fine assumption and may well be the case. I just think its worth mentioning rather than stating outright that "a Synthetic Event is pooled" since that's no longer the case.

Comment: Actually, I am using 17.0.2 but your solution works.

Comment: @TToprak1 I'm glad to help you

Comment: Another minor point of clarity, React state updater functions are actually completely synchronous but it's the state updates they enqueue that are asynchronously processed. In other words, it's the React state updates that are asynchronous in nature. You can't await a state update.

Comment: @DrewReese Thanks for pointing that out, I updated that part.